# Pyinstaller executables slow to start and the filesize is too large

Tags: import, pyinstaller, python-venv, nuitka

i've trying to convert a simple python code to create  a desktop application.
This are the libraries i have to import:

```
from ctypes import alignment,windll
from win32api import GetMonitorInfo,MonitorFromPoint
import logging
import sys
from os import path, makedirs
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QRect, Qt, QLocale
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont,QIcon,QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHeaderView,QMainWindow,QAbstractScrollArea,QCompleter, QLineEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QComboBox, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QSpinBox, QLabel, QTableWidget, QDoubleSpinBox, QCheckBox, QApplication

from pandas import DataFrame, ExcelWriter
import xlsxwriter
```

I've tried both with --onefile and --onedir mode but the application is quite large (more than 200MB) and **very slow** to start.

I tried also excluding many libraries such as numpy scipy matplotlib seaborn... no matter what the file is still big and if I exclude them it seems not to run.
I would like to to find a way to make pyinstaller import only the part of the libraries i've specified in my scripts and not as instance the whole pandas package. I could rewrite the part of code where I use dataframes to make it completly indipendent from pandas, anyway I'm assuming that there is a smarter and more correct approach to use pyinstaller.

I've read that it is suggested to use a virtual environment to use pyinstaller, can anyone explain me in details how to do so and use it to import all the libraries i need in this project?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I've removed pandas from the algorithm, now the size of the one file if approximatly 36MB. Can't figure a better way to set the .spec file in order to install only the required part of the libraries.